# how to use Windows API(user32.dll) in java 

Tags: java, winapi

Is there any way to use Windows API i.e user32.dll in java??

Answer (score 4):

Use [JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna) - Also see the [Java Native Access](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access) page on wikipedia.

Comment: @RealHowTo Ahh i was using an old bookmark - it did redirect though. Edited post, TY :)

Answer (score 3):

You may use:

- [JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna) (as already written in previous replies)
- [Bridj](https://github.com/nativelibs4java/BridJ). Bridj is a project younger than JNA and still have limitations but it also has some nice features: generics support, faster than JNA, annotation-based API...

Answer (score 0):

Certainly is.  Take a look at http://www.codeguru.com/java/tij/tij0193.shtml for a discussion of J/Direct which lets you interface with just about any api.  The example there is in fact user32.dll

Edit: J/Direct is no longer maintained and is also Windows only, might well be better off with Erik's JNA suggestion above